# React Hooks Calling GET Request On Modal Popup

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I am trying to create a Modal is react and call a get request to load details of a task.

I have most of it working (I think), but essentially what I have done is createa custom Modal Hook that toggles two modals.

The second of the two modals is meant to open a task and render the task details in a form for editing but I am unable to get it working.

Here is the useModal hook:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useModal = () => {
const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);
const [secondModalIsShowing, secondModalSetIsShowing] = useState(false);

function toggle() {
  setIsShowing(!isShowing);
}

function secondToggle() {
  secondModalSetIsShowing(!secondModalIsShowing);
  console.log("clicked");
}

return {
   isShowing,
   toggle,
   secondModalIsShowing,
   secondToggle,
  };
};

export default useModal;
```

I then call the function for the secondToggle which fires the code below to render the modal. Now as you may see I have to comment out the section where it calls getTask() with match.params.id, as well as the  component that is then meant to be rendered in the modal.

If I don't do that I get an error message with the following " Line 23:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions"

```
  import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import { connect } from "react-redux";
  import PropTypes from "prop-types";
  import TaskItem from "../tasks/task-item/TaskItem";
  import { getTask } from "../../actions/task";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  import "./Modal.styles.scss";
  import "../dashboard/Dashboard.styles.scss";
  import Task from "../task/Task";
  import TaskEdit from "../task/TaskEdit";


  const TaskModal = ({
    getTask,
    task: { task, loading },
    match,
    secondModalIsShowing,
    hide,
  }) => {
const [displayEdit, toggleDisplayEdit] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   getTask();
   // match.params.id;
 }, [getTask]);

 return secondModalIsShowing
   ? ReactDOM.createPortal(
       <React.Fragment>
         <button
           type="submit"
           value="toggle"
           onClick={() => toggleDisplayEdit(!displayEdit)}
         >
            Show/Edit
         </button>
         {(displayEdit && <TaskItem task={task} />) || (
           <div>{/* <TaskEdit /> */}</div>
         )}
         <div className="modal-overlay" />
         <div
           className="modal-wrapper"
           aria-modal
           aria-hidden
           tabIndex={-1}
           role="dialog"
         >
              <div className="modal">
             <div className="modal-header">
               Add New Task
               <button
                 type="button"
                 className="modal-header__button"
                 data-dismiss="modal"
                 aria-label="Close"
                 onClick={hide}
               >
                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </React.Fragment>,
       document.body
     )
   : null;
  };
```

Now if I render this EditTask component outside the modal as a normal component it works correctly. I can also get the modal to render when it's not trying to display the EditTask component.

As a result, I think it's related to the Route path and passing the response to the TaskModal component? When I click the modal to open I cant get it to render the URL with the task ID and therefore I cant render the details of the task in the modal.

```
  <Route path="/taskedit/:id" component={TaskModal} />
```

For context, I think this guide comes close to solving my issue (https://blog.logrocket.com/building-a-modal-module-for-react-with-react-router/) but I am not familiar with working with class-based components and when I try and convert to functional-based components I'm running into even more issues.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide as I keep trying to work through this.

Paul

Answer (score 2):

The first issue I am seeing is you have to pass the task id to TaskModal component

```
    <Route path="/taskedit/:id"
           render={(props) => <TaskModal {...props} />}>
   </Route>
```

This will make the task id available as property in TaskModal.
Then in the TaskModal, fetch like below

```
let taskid = prop.match.params.id;
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, that's at least got the component rendering again, albeit not as a modal just yet. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @PaulTowers Thanks